# Display metadata in Finder "more Info" for a file with system extension

Tags: macos, info.plist, uti

I need to display some metadata (kMDItemTitle) in Finder file info dialog, "More Info" panel. There is no problem to write the data from command line (xattr) and in runtime (setxattr). For some file types (such as .png or .tga) the written data are displayed ok, but not for my .img files because same extension is used by DiskImageMounter system util.

I've read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354044/custom-spotlight-importer-and-finders-get-info-more-info-section). As I've understood, I can't assign my/another UTI for the .img file, it stays as set by DiskImageMounter
(com.apple.disk-image-ndif). So I set this UTI as [imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpGP0.png) in my info.plist. I hoped the "Conform" UTI will be added to UTI tree and thus my title info will be displayed. But it did not happen

So what am I doing/understanding wrong? And what is a sense to use imported UTI if "conform" has no effect? And is it possible at all to display "Title" metadata in "More Info" without writting a custom importer?

Thx